# "This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store" error while running project in vs code

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, visual-studio-code

I am running an asp.net core project in vs code using

`dotnet run`

And it provides the following output

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

But when I open it in the browser at port 5001 it shows HTTPS in red with a dashed line, Not secure tag, and gives this message

> This CA Root certificate is not trusted. To enable trust, install this certificate in the Trusted root certification authorities store

I am unable to find a solution for this. I want to run my project on HTTPS in localhost.
Do I have to do some settings in vs code or install some certificate?
I have checked this in multiple browsers and the issue persists everywhere.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58957501/6181928

Answer (score -1):

Why not just ignore that and keep continue cause it's just development self-sign certification for development purpose ?

We can keep continue like this (it's almost identical on both chrome and firefox)
[image: Ignore certification warning]

If you curious, this is a brief about how it works.

Every https connection make use of a certification (that can be self signed or provide from a Certificate Authority).

If it was self-signed, there was no certification chained under the hood, therefore, the root certification that was accepted on the machine cannot verified that's it safe (cannot verify where the certificate come from, which is ofcourse, we make it ourself). Then the browser knows that a server that was hosted on `localhost` are using a suspicious certification that came out of nowhere and cannot be verified. Therefore, she gave a warning. Which again, just ignore it cause we're on development process.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but I want to use it with HTTPS due to Google OAuth where I do not have access to change registered URI for now.

Comment: Do we have some misunderstood here ? I make use of Google OAuth all the time, even not setting up https on my localhost. When the request come to google endpoint. The TLS things auto negotiate security level invoved with that request, which only affect the HttpClient request itself... What possible could it be with our localhost certificate anyway ?

Comment: No, Actually you have to provide Authorized javascript origins while using google OAuth. My URI is registered with HTTPS. I do not have access to change it now and That's why I want to run it on HTTPS.

Comment: If we dont have permission to change origins, how about use your own account to register another app that config not using https ? Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZltDK.png) ? Still using google oauth, still sign-in by our own account, if any information or extra scope was needed then just specify them out ?